# How to change color style of TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, styles, textfield

I have a simple TextField widget like this

```
TextField(
      obscureText: widget.placeholder == "Password" ? _isHidePassword : false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        
        hintText: "${widget.placeholder}",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        // labelText: "${widget.placeholder}",
        // labelStyle: TextStyle(color: greenMain),
      ),
    )
```

and it gives the result like this picture:
[image]

is there a way to change the blue color into another? like red or green one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets try

```
Theme(
        data: new ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.redAccent,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            
            labelText: "Text field*",
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the decoration on `TextField` like this:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: 'Type Text Here',        
enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(      
borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),   
),
```

And this will change the line to color red.

I hope i help you

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have try it, the line color become red but whenever I click the TextForm, the color will change into blue again

Comment: You'll need to use the focusedBorder property in that case @uyhaW